# How to get userinput in java language in eclipse?

Tags: java, android

I am new here , am very interested in making android app's.
how are you all Expert's
shall you join me in making and resolving app and making concept clear where  hit problem ?

Is user input in java is only through import untility scanner file or  is there any another function available ?

import java.util.scanner;

i think java command line argument do the same work as scanner utility ???

Comment: normally I'm using `EditText` for user input ... `java.util.Scanner` is for simple primitive types parsing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bufferedreader(new inputstreamreader(system.in));
```

or alternately u can go with java.util.Scanner